# javascript regular expression to validate data types

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to validate data types.
The example is about requiring a number for questions asking numerical value and string for string value question.

So I tried to construct my if statement so that if the first question or the second question is about 'father' or 'number' and the answer is NOT a number, throw an alert, etc.

Would like to have another else if statement that says if the question is about such and such (requiring a string answer) AND the answer is NOT a string, throw an alert.

It's giving me the "You must type in a number" for any type of key down press event, regardless of whether the key is a number or a string character...
I appreciate any input.. Thanks.

```
    function validateDataType(word) {
        firstSelection = document.getElementById('firstQ').value;
        secondSelection = document.getElementById('secondQ').value;
        try{
            if ((firstSelection=="number"|firstSelection=="father"|secondSelection=="number"|secondSelection=="father")&&(!/^(?=.*\d).$/.test(word)))
            throw "You must type in a number.";
            else if (!/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).$/.test(word))
            throw "You must type in text.";

        }
        catch(inputError){
            window.alert(inputError);
            return false
        }
        finally {
            document.forms[0].firstA.value ='';
            document.forms[0].secondA.value = '';
        }
        document.open();
        document.write("You entered valid answers");
        document.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `||` instead of `|` in your if condition:

```
if ((firstSelection=="number"||firstSelection=="father"||secondSelection=="number"||secondSelection=="father")&&(!/^(?=.*\d).$/.test(word)))
```

- `|` is used for bitwise OR

Comment: This should not be a problem with booleans, am I wrong ?